# How to remove last row in table and set it as first row in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried following function downward() for removing last row and insert it as first row whereas display() function just creates the table.

```
    <body>
    <script>
        function downward() {
                    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
                    var count = table.rows.length - 1;
                    var table = table[count];
                    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                    var shifted = rows[count];
                    rows[count].parentNode.removeChild(rows[count]);
                    table.insertBefore(rows[0]);

                }
    function display() {
        var table = document.createElement('table');

        table.setAttribute("id", "tbl");

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var text = document.createTextNode(j+i);

                td.appendChild(text);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    }
    </script>
<input id="display" type="button" value="Display" onclick="display();" />
<input id="downward" type="button" value="downward" onclick="downward();" />
    </body>
```

Comment: because document.getElementsByTagName('table'); returns a collection and you treat it as a single element.  Look at the developer console for errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.removeChild` to remove the last child and insert it before the first element using `.insertBefore`. See example:

```js
function myFunction(){
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var tr = document.getElementById("myTable").lastChild;
table.removeChild[document.getElementsByTagName("tr").lenght];
table.insertBefore(tr, document.getElementById("myTable").firstChild);
}
```

```html
<table><tbody id="myTable"><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="click me to see the result">click me to see the result</button>
```